# What's wrong with this code - passing a value by reference in C++?

Tags: c++

So I've been trying to create a factorial function in C++ which calculates factorial of a number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int& x)
{
  int b=x-1;

  if(x>1)
    return(x*=factorial(b));
  else
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
  int a;

  cout<<"Enter the number to get factorial (and press enter):\n";
  cin>>a;
  factorial(a);
  cout<<endl<<a;

  return 0;
}
```

The code above works, but if I replace this code

```
return(x*=factorial(b));
```

with

```
return(x*=factorial(x-1));
```

it doesn't work. 
It reports an error saying: "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'", can someone explain please, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Better split the return and the assignment into separate lines. I'm also a beginner and I wouldn't dare to write such dangerous code in C++.

Comment: But what's the difference: if I type in "2" or "1+1"?

Comment: @user2684291 That's not what it's about. The difference is between variables and temporary values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x - 1` is not an lvalue: it doesn't designate storage, and as such, you can't assign to/modify it. Just think about that for a moment: `x - 1 *= <something>` doesn't make sense. Hence, it is illegal to pass an rvalue to a function taking a non-`const` reference.

Comment: See, I didn't know it requires an lvalue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You take int by reference and you're trying to bind an rvalue to it. `b` is an lvalue (something you can take the address of), `x - 1` is result of an expression, that is, an rvalue (something you can't take the address of).

Answer (score 0):

Passing an argument by reference means that when you call

```
factorial(a);
```

the function is actually called with the *address* of variable `a`, so the function can change the value that's stored there.  A function that's called by reference must always get an argument that's an *lvalue* -- a value that can go on the left side of an assignment statement, so the compiler can instead give the function the address of that value.

If you try to call such a function like this:

```
factorial(x-1);
```

the compiler has no way of making sense of it, because there's no way to assign a value to `x-1`. That expression is an *rvalue:* something that can only appear on the right side of an assignment statement.

That explains the compiler's cryptic error message a bit:

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'

The compiler needs the argument to `factorial` to be a "non-const reference of type 'int&'", i.e. a reference to a variable that it can modify ("non-const"). You've called it instead with `x-1`, which is "an rvalue of type int", and it's telling you that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thank you for further explanation. It makes sense now.

Comment: "the function is actually called with the address of variable a" - no, it isn't.